# Perl Recursive Explanation

Tags: perl, recursion, hashmap

I have following script that need to understand

```
&main('key_1');

sub main {
    @{$tmp{'key_1'}} = ("A", "B");
    @{$tmp{'A'}} = ("C");

    &test_recurse(\%tmp, 'key_1');
}

sub test_recurse {
    my ($hash, $cell) = @_;
    foreach my $cur_subcell (@{$hash->{$cell}}){
        &test_recurse($hash, $cur_subcell);
    }
    print "X($cell)\n";
}
```

The output:

```
X(C)
X(A)
X(B)
X(key_1)
```

I want to understand why the `key_1` is printing at the last? I am expecting the `key_1` might not be printed at all.

Comment: You are passing `key_1` from `main()` to `test_recurse()` as the `$cell` argument so it will be printed (when the last line of `test_recurse()` is executed)

Comment: is this the default behavior onto printing the key at the last? i am seeing that when multiple hierarchy hash is involved the key will be printed at the last of the loop, i thought the value has be completely overwritten

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve. Please explain what you are trying to do, then it will be easier to suggest alternative solutions

Comment: Why do you want the `X(C)` to be printed? It is not a part of the `key_1` array

Comment: I am actually trying to understand some piece of code, and come across this part that do not understand clearly, the code is basically tell to sort the hash according to the hierarchy, I am just thinking that as if the variable ````$cell```` has been replace by C, A, B why the ````key_1```` is coming back at the end. I am just trying to understand the reasonable behind that.

Comment: [Please don't use ampersands to call subroutines](https://perlhacks.com/2015/04/subroutines-and-ampersands/) - they are unnecessary and potentially confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment, you say:

> I am just thinking that as if the variable `$cell` has been replace by C, A, B why the `key_1` is coming back at the end.

And I think that's probably a good indication of where the confusion lies.

Your `test_recurse()` subroutine starts with this line:

```
my ($hash, $cell) = @_;
```

That defines two new variables called `$hash` and `$cell` and then populates them from `@_`. Because these variables are declared using `my`, they are **lexical** variables. That means they are only visible within the block of code where they are declared.

Later on in `test_recurse()` you call the same subroutine again. And, once again, that subroutine starts with the same declaration statement and creates **another** two variables called `$hash` and `$cell`. These two new variables are completely separate from the original two variables. The original variables still exist and still contain their original values - but you can't currently access them because they are declared in a different call to the subroutine.

So when your various calls to the subroutine end, you rewind back to the original call - and that still has the original two variables which still hold their original values.

Comment: So, basically i will say it is having the multiple ````test_recurse()```` that is going on at one time, am i  right to say that?

Comment: @user1550596: That's right. But the important thing is that each instance of `test_recurse()` has its own, completely separate, set of variables.

Answer (score 2):

> I am expecting the `key_1` might not be printed at all

The function `test_recurse` ends with `print "X($cell)\n"`. This means that it ends by printing its second argument. Since you initially call it with `key_1` as argument, it prints `X(key_1)`.

To understand a bit better how the function `test_recurse` works, I suggest to add some prints as follows:

```
sub test_recurse {
    my ($hash, $cell, $offset) = @_;
    print "${offset}test_recurse($cell)\n";
    foreach my $cur_subcell (@{$hash->{$cell}}){
        &test_recurse($hash, $cur_subcell, $offset . "  ");
    }
    print "${offset}X($cell)\n";
}
```

Thanks to the addition of `$offset`, each time you make a recursive call, the prints within this recursive call are indented further to the right. Calling this modified function with `test_recurse(\%tmp, 'key_1', "")`, you'll get this output:

```
test_recurse(key_1)
  test_recurse(A)
    test_recurse(C)
    X(C)
  X(A)
  test_recurse(B)
  X(B)
X(key_1)
```

So, what happens is:

- You call `test_recurse` with `key_1`. This prints `test_recurse(key_1)`.
  In the foreach loop, it will make two successive calls to `test_recurse`:

  - The first one with `A` as argument. This will print `test_recurse(A)`.
    In the foreach loop, it will make a call to

    - `test_recurse` with `C` as argument. This will print `test_recurse(C)`.
      Since `$tmp{C}` does not exist, this call does not enter in the `foreach` loop, and directly proceed to the final print and prints `X(C)`. We then go back to the caller (`test_recurse` with `A` as argument).

    Now that the `foreach` loop is done, this function moves on to the last `print` and prints `X(A)`. We then go back to the caller (`test_recurse` with `key_1` as argument).
  - The second recursive call is to `test_recurse` with `B` as argument. This will print `test_recurse(B)`. Since `$tmp{B}` does not exist, we do not enter the `foreach` loop and move on to the final print, which prints `X(B)`. We then return to the caller (`test_recurse` with `key_1` as argument).

  The `foreach` loop is now over and we move on to the final `print`, which prints `X(key_1)`.

---

Some tips:

- Always add `use strict` and `use warnings` at the beginning of your scripts.
- `@{$tmp{'key_1'}} = ("A", "B");` would be clearer as `$tmp{'key_1'} = [ 'A', 'B' ]`.
- The whole initialization of `%tmp` could actually be done with:

  ```
  my %tmp = (
      key_1 => [ 'A', 'B' ],
      A     => [ 'C' ]
  );
  ```
- You call `&main('key_1');` with `key_1` as argument, but `main` does not expect any argument.
- To call a function, you don't need `&`: do `test_recurse(\%tmp, 'key_1');` instead of `&test_recurse(\%tmp, 'key_1');`.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply, it is very much clearer, so i assume that the key will be printed out as soon as each ````test_recurse````is over, so this is the default behavior right?

Comment: @user1550596 The key will be printed as soon as `test_recurse` reaches `print "X($cell)\n";`.  I'm not sure as to why you mean by "this is the default behavior".

Comment: I am actually a bit confusing with the redefinition of ````my $cell````, it should have been overwritten each time the function called.